# How to change my loyalty program online before check-in?

Tags: loyalty-programs, lufthansa, miles-and-more

I have made a booking with Lufthansa and initially listed my Miles & More account for credit of eventual miles gained. However now I want to credit the miles that will be gained from the flight to another mileage program (compatible with LH).

I can access my booking online via the Lufthansa website/My bookings. I was able to add the other mileage program to the "Passenger" item of my booking but now it shows both the Miles & More and the other program (with my numbers) and I have no idea which one will be used to credit my miles to.

**How can I choose which loyalty program to credit the miles to?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Doing so seems impossible before check-in but is no hassle at (online-) check-in.**

So I did call up website support and customer service of Lufthansa and Miles & More. Staff was not knowledgeable on my request and they even wrongly told me there was no chance to change the loyalty program selected during booking at all (but the same employee did take out the originally selected program from the records).

However it was **no problem selecting the milage program to which to credit miles at online check-in**.

Answer (score 5):

There are up to 4 fields that a booking can contain to do with your frequent flyer number:
  - FQTR - FF# used as source of a redemption booking
  - FQTS - FF# used for status, i.e. lounge entry
  - FQTV - FF# of account that will be credited
  - FQTU - FF# of account used to upgrade

They're not all available, and even if they were, often the airline agents aren't trained to use them all since having more than one in a PNR is uncommon.

It sounds like you have an FQTS and an FQTV entry in your booking, but you want to be sure that FQTV is correct. You can try bringing up the booking in any other star alliance member web site, but if you wish to be sure, you should call the airline.

There's another complication in that the flight information is transferred to the departure control system (DCS), it's possible to end up with boarding passes that indicate one FF# and the credit is made to a previously entered account, depending on when you update the information, and how it is done.

If it's more than a few days out, I would call the airline, otherwise I would change the number at check-in. Get a printed boarding pass with your FF# on it so that you can submit it if the account is not credited.

Comment: That's interesting but I'm not sure that's what I'm seeing. The programs are not listed as FQTx, just as belonging to me as passenger. I'm not sure where during check-in I can specify that (flight is in a few days), I'd rather figure it out in advance because so far my M&M had been selected automatically when checking in (but was also the only program on record).

Comment: You'll never see FQTx. They're only visible on the PNR or via a GDS. They're dubmed down for passengers.

Comment: Any change on LH's website or any other airline site almost certainly changes FQTV. But I'd call to make sure. Read: http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/aegean-airlines-miles-bonus/1571575-fqts-fqtv-not-possible-lh.html

Comment: Just called LH after twitter didn't help, they told me to call M&M which surely won't help either... should I try at check-in?

Comment: You should also be able to change it a OLCI and of course at the airport. I think LH's twitter probably didn't understand what you wanted to do properly

Comment: So M&M had me call LH again and they say it is not possible to change the program at all after booking which I find surprising... had them via the call center take out the number from the booking but still possible that miles will be credited to M&M, if not I'm lucky and could in retrospect claim with the other progam

Comment: That's nonsense! However getting them to take it out is a good first step. Can you add it back on on LH?

Comment: It is taken out now and I will not dare put in back on. Will also be careful at check-in and seek staff if things get weird.